# How to set download path and get the download path?

Tags: android, file, android-download-manager

```
      request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,nameOfFile);
```

How to read the downloaded file from that dir.

```
          File file = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,nameOfFile);
            MimeTypeMap map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.getName());
            String type = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
```

Getting the error that file could not be accessed.

Comment: Have you added proper permissions in Android Manifest? Read and Write external storage?

Comment: Did you check the external storage state?

Comment: @Pooja Gaikwad   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> all permission  given

Comment: @Jonas Koritz I am checking it on device and I am able to see the downloads

Comment: provide the stacktrace of the error

Comment: Thanks @Pooja Gaikwad   Jonas solved the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use the function: `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), nameOfFile);
```

See the [Android API Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String))